# How to drag KDE programs to the Launcher in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, launcher, ktorrent

I am trying to drag Ktorrent to the launcher but the Launcher does not accept Ktorrent. It just bounces back and it does not get added. When the ktorrent icon dragged on top of the launcher, the whole launcher goes gray (Am grabbing the ktorrent from the Dash search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as a [bug](http://pad.lv/774211).

You can still pin a KDE app to the launcher by running it. Right click on the launcher item and select "Keep in Launcher"